Only home page is visible ,404 not found error for other pages after hosting through digital ocean. Laravel project
I have created a droplet and setup following this tutorial - text
I created a subdomain in godaddy and pointed towards the digitalocean droplet ip.
I cloned my project from Gitlab.
I imported the .sql file and also configured the .env file of my project . I also configured the apache.conf and virtual host file . I do not have a ssl certificate .I'm planning to host it that way (it's a staging website).
what will be the possible problems. Is it with the config files ?
